# Variable padding C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let's say we have a variable `x` of 64 bits, we also know how many bits of such variable we actually use, say `1 <= nx <= 64` , so the last bit is in position `nx - 1`. What could be the fastest way to perform a padding of the last bit in the remaining `64 - nx`?

I would try something like (pseudocode/C):

```
uint64_t padd_input(uint64_t x, int nx) {
    assert(0 < nx && nx <= 64);
    msb = (x & (1ULL<<(nx - 1))) != 0ULL; //or (x >> (nx - 1)) & 0x1ULL;
    x |= ((msb<<(64 - nx)) - msb)<<nx;   
    return x;
}
```

Is all the shift/masking redundant? Or is there a smarter way to achieve the same thing?

I make an example of I want to achieve, assume the unused part is already set to 0.

Let's say i have `0x7`, and `nx = 4` in this case there's nothing to do. Assuming instead `0xF` the padding has to provide `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: It looks like your code is not doing anything when `msb` is zero, and `msb` is set to zero when bit in position `nx-1` is zero. This is not intentional, is it?

Comment: Actually it is intentional (I've assumed the "unused part" is already set to 0). Even though we drop the assumption I just need an "if statement", I guess. If(msb) {x |= leading_ones} else {x &= leading zeroes} or I mask the less significant part (still an and operation).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight There's an example in the original question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "padding"? It seems as if you are trying to sign-extend?

Comment: Say you have a binary number <code>x[63]x[62]...x[nx-1]x[nx - 2] ... x[0]</code>, adn assume I'm using the first <code>nx</code> digits.  By padding I mean assign <code>x[63]...x[nx] = x[nx-1]...x[nx-1]</code>.

Comment: And yes, a context could be a sign extension, but not necessarily that.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
uint64_t padd_input(uint64_t x, int nx)
{
    uint64_t t = x & (1ULL << (nx-1));
    t = t - 1;
    x = x | ~t;
    return x;
}
```

or perhaps

```
uint64_t padd_input(uint64_t x, int nx)
{
    uint64_t t = x & (1ULL << (nx-1));
    if (t)
    {
        t = t - 1;
        x = x | ~t;
    }
    return x;
}
```

as it seems more clear to me.

Note: I have not compared performance of OPs code and my code.

Comment: The first one seems interesting.

Comment: @user8469759 - the result is of cause the same for both. It's only a question about whether you want the `if` or you always want to do `t = t - 1; x = x | ~t;` , i.e. for `t == 0` those two lines do not change `x`.

Comment: I wait whether someone else adds other answers. But your one, the first, is very clean.